# status bar goes black while showing bottom sheet dialog

Tags: java, android, statusbar

how do I prevention the status bar from loosing it's color while a bottom sheet is showing up?

I use a `bottom sheet view with custom layout.`
tried modify the style of the dialog but still no luck

here is my code

```
   if (position == 1) {
                View modalbottomsheet = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.others_sheet, null);
                dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(getActivity());
                dialog.setContentView(modalbottomsheet);
                dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                dialog.setCancelable(true);
                dialog.show();

                contact_num = (EditText) modalbottomsheet.findViewById(editText);
                choose_contact = (Button) modalbottomsheet.findViewById(choose);
                choose_contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (v.getId() == choose_contact.getId()) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
                        }

                    }
                });
                hidetext = (EditText) modalbottomsheet.findViewById(R.id.hidetext);
                recharge_btn = (Button) modalbottomsheet.findViewById(R.id.rechargeothers_btn);
                recharge_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (v.getId()== recharge_btn.getId()){
                            String phone = ((EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText)).getText().toString();
                            String hidden = ((EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.hidetext)).getText().toString();
                            String pre = "*805*2";
                            String hash = "%23";
                            String dail = "tel:" + pre + phone + hidden + hash;
                            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(dail)));
                            dialog.hide();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: Can you at least share your code of something?

Comment: show your code atleast.